# How to copy XML file in to MySQL field for analysis?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a website which sends data to a third party supplier. They then send back XML with fields containing information about the data.

How can I copy this XML to a MySQL table?

I've looked everywhere and lots of importing XML to MySQL threads, but this is not what I am looking to do. I just want the XML file in a MySQL field.

Do I need to convert it to a string / array first?

Comment: you want the whole xml file in the db? if so why, just store it as a file

Comment: If you only want to store all content of the XML file in a MySQL field, you can use the `file_get_content()` PHP function, to get the file content and then store it using a Query.

Comment: Be aware that the XML parser in MySQL does not support namespaces. If you're going to extract data from the XML in queries, you might need to convert the XML during your import.

Comment: In the end I was able to just copy the response back in to a string, and then in to an array which was then posted to the DB. Not ideal, but works and does what I wanted it to do. Did not want to store the xml files themselves as there would end up being too many over a long period of time.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this myself. I ended up just extracting the responses from the XML as a comma separated string which I then posted.